# php is in array or search array doesnt seems to work

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks as follows when printed to the screen

Array ( [0] => Array ( [9] => false ) )

Im trying to search it for a 9 however it keeps failing.  I have tried in_array and array_search but both seem to fail and are not echoing out anything to the screen.  Here is my code

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult)){  

            $serialApple = unserialize($row['idusersApple']);

            if(in_array(9, $serialApple)){
            //do something ace
            echo'this is ace';
            }
    }
```

Comment: try `if(isset($serialApple[0][9]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**9** is a key, not a value. Find **9** in keys

```
if(in_array(9, array_keys($serialApple[0]))){
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/449561)**

Answer (score 0):

To check for existence of a key use `array_key_exists(9, $serialApple)`.

Check details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array

Which is not your case so you have to do `array_key_exists`

> [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) — Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult)){  

    $serialApple = unserialize($row['idusersApple']);

    if(array_key_exists(9, $serialApple)){
        //do something ace
        echo'this is ace';
    }
}
```